# How to show my own media player in "complete action using " pop up for play file by my media player

Tags: android

I am create media player that play mp3 file. But when i click on any mp3 file it shows one pop up. it contains all media player rather than my own. Please help to show it in that pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the following intent-filters to your activity in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

If you want your app to show up only for mp3 files, try this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/mp3" />  
    <data android:pathPattern="*.mp3" />
</intent-filter>
```

To read more on intent filters: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs).

Comment: thanx. its working. but now i am getting problem to play that file which user have selected. will i get any call back listener on my activity which extend media player, so that i will have the path which i will play through media player.how will i get that which file i have to play?

Comment: @RaviShinde In your activity's `onCreate(Bundle)`, retrieve data from the intent. `Uri data = getIntent().getData();`. Use this Uri to play the file.